# Flutter and Iot devices

Tags: flutter, dart, esp32, platformio

I am currently building an app that controls a single actuator and a LED strip. The controller for the actuator and LED strip is based on an **ESP32**.
On the **ESP32** I have used the `<ESPAsyncWebServer.h>`, `<ESPAsyncWiFiManager.h>` to set up and connect the ESP to the local wireless network. In the app I would like to send some commands to the ESP like `http://<ESP32_IP>/led_set?level=<level>` and
`http://<ESP32_IP>/act_open` and so on, this shouldn't be an issue.

Normally I would set up **mDNS** on the ESP and in the Flutter app, however several of the ESP controllers are already shipped to the customers. So I am looking for another way to identify the ESP.

At the moment I have used the [ping_discover_network](https://pub.dev/packages/ping_discover_network) library and the ESP shows up fine on port 80. I am however not able to separate the ESP from the other devices that shows up on port 80.

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe take a look to ``nmap``. It has an option ``-O`` to check the os. https://nmap.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have many good options. If you only want to identify a few devices which have slipped through your fingers without mDNS, you can use their MAC address as a filter. If you happen to know their individual MAC addresses, then that should be quite painless. Otherwise you'd have to look for devices with MAC OUI (first 3 bytes, usually) ranges allocated to Espressif. Espressif has several OUI ranges, but if your devices were from a single batch of ESP32 module of the same type, they'll be using the same OUI so it should be quite easy to figure out.

E.g. a batch of modules I have all start with `40:F5:20:...`

Of course, if a third party installs their (unrelated) ESP32 module into the same network, you'll have a chance of identifying those as well, but such is life.

This is obviously a stop-gap measure. Make sure further devices go out of door with some identification (mDNS or otherwise).